# Set click listeners for different parts of the same image

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have a single body image that looks something like this

[image]

What I need to do is differentiate a click on the different parts of the body.
For eg, if the head is clicked, then a function `onHeadClicked` should execute. If I click on the left hand, then a function `onLeftHandClicked`. How will this work?

Comment: I have a solution to that. I'm using it in my app. It's a bit cumbersome, but it works fine even doing zoom in the image and showing it in different density screens. Let me arrive at home and I'll post the code. Anyway, if there is a better solution than mine, I'd like to know it, this is why I upvoted

Comment: So I've arrived at home and read Niza answer. My solution basically works using the same principle, using the ImageView's matrix, but is more complex. Since is hard to explain, if you are also interested in my solution, let me know and I'll post it for you. Regards

Comment: @MarcEstrada please do post your solution. I will try them both. Thank you

Comment: I've just posted it :)

Comment: Hey @SriramR did you see my solution?

Comment: @MarcEstrada yes I did see your solution. I didn't get a chance to try it out yet as I have been busy at work. I will try it out tonight and get back to you.

Comment: Great, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning:** This solution has at least 5 years (I'm still using it), so surely is outdated and maybe there are new technologies to solve better this problem. Anyway, I'll post the solution here in order to help you. Also, this solution is a bit cumbersome and you maybe could refactor or improve it, feel free to do it.

## Summary

This solution is based in 2 images, one of them will be visible (which one you want to show to the user) and the other will be invisible.

The invisible image must have the same pixel size than the target image (in your case the body image), will be transparent (or black-backgrounded) and will have the different zones you want to click filled with distinct colors.

So, when you click the target image, the coordinates of its matrix are checked, and then starting to this coordinates, the color of the pressed pixel is get from the second image.

Since you know which color corresponds to which part of the body (because you previously has configured a map with color->part_of_body), getting one color you could know exactly the part of the body clicked.

## Solution

You have your target image:

[image]

Then, you need to create the second image, as follows:

[image]

See that you have now each part of the body marked with a distinct color. Please note that the colors are notably different. This is why if you use similar colors, could be conflicts at the time to retrieve the part of the body because colors could de confused.

Afterwards, you need to export the colors image with transparent background and you should get the following (please note the background is transparent, but the background of StackOverflow is white):

[image]

You will work with first and third images, the second one is only a intermediate step.

First of all, you have to configure in code your Map color->part_of_body:

```
public HashMap<Integer, String> bodyParts;
bodyParts.put(parseColor("#ff0000"), "part_1");
bodyParts.put(parseColor("#00ff00"), "part_2");
bodyParts.put(parseColor("#0000ff"), "part_3");
bodyParts.put(parseColor("#ffff00"), "part_4");
... // Finish here with all your parts and colors
```

Then I've made a custom `ImageView` in order to handle easier the images:

**ZoneTapImageView.java**

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;

    public class ZoneTapImageView extends FrameLayout implements PhotoViewAttacher.OnPhotoTapListener {
      private static final String LOG_TAG = "ZoneMapTouch";
      private static final int DEFAULT_TOLERANCE = 25;

      private ImageView imageView;
      private ImageView imageViewAreas;
      @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
      private HashMap<Integer, String> areasMap = new HashMap<>();
      private Context context;
      private OnAreaObtainedListener areaObtainedListener;
      private PhotoViewAttacher imageViewAttacher;
      private PhotoViewAttacher imageViewAreasAttacher;

      public ZoneTapImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
      }

      public ZoneTapImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
      }

      public ZoneTapImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
      }

      private void init(Context context) {
        int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.groups_padding_mini);

        this.context = context;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        this.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        imageViewAreas = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageViewAreas.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageViewAreas.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageViewAreas.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageViewAreas.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageViewAreas.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        this.addView(imageViewAreas);
        this.addView(imageView);
      }

      public void setImageResources(int resIdImage, int resIdImageAreas) {
        setImageResource(resIdImage);
        setImageResourceAreas(resIdImageAreas);
      }

      public void setImageResource(final int resIdImage) {
        imageView.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // Here I use a Image Cache, but it's not necessary
            ImageMemoryCache.loadBitmap(context, resIdImage, imageView, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), new ImageMemoryCache.OnImageLoadedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onImageLoaded() {
                if (imageViewAttacher == null) {
                  imageViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
                  imageViewAttacher.setZoomable(true);
                  imageViewAttacher.setOnPhotoTapListener(ZoneTapImageView.this);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }

      public void setImageResourceAreas(final int resIdImageAreas) {
        imageViewAreas.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // Here I use a Image Cache, but it's not necessary
            ImageMemoryCache.loadBitmap(context, resIdImageAreas, imageViewAreas, imageViewAreas.getWidth(), imageViewAreas.getHeight(), new ImageMemoryCache.OnImageLoadedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onImageLoaded() {
                if (imageViewAreasAttacher == null) {
                  imageViewAreasAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageViewAreas);
                  imageViewAreasAttacher.setZoomable(false);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }

      public void setZoomOut() {
        if (imageViewAttacher != null)
          imageViewAttacher.setScale(1, true);
      }

      public void setOnAreaObtainedListener(OnAreaObtainedListener areaObtainedListener) {
        this.areaObtainedListener = areaObtainedListener;
      }

      @Override
      public void onPhotoTap(View view, float x, float y) {
        if (imageViewAreasAttacher == null) return;
        final RectF displayRect = imageViewAreasAttacher.getDisplayRect();

        float xAbsolute = x * displayRect.width() + displayRect.left;
        float yAbsolute = y * displayRect.height() + displayRect.top;

        Log.d("MapTouch", "X: " + xAbsolute + " Y: " + yAbsolute);
        getAreaFromCoordinatesAsync((int) xAbsolute, (int) yAbsolute, areaObtainedListener);
      }

      public void setAreasMap(HashMap<Integer, String> areasMap) {
        this.areasMap = areasMap;
      }

      public void getAreaFromCoordinatesAsync(final int x, final int y, final OnAreaObtainedListener onAreaObtainedListener) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            String area = getAreaFromCoordinates(x, y);
            if (onAreaObtainedListener != null) {
              onAreaObtainedListener.OnArea(area);
            }
          }
        }).start();
      }

      public String getAreaFromCoordinates(int x, int y) {
        int touchColor = getTapColor(x, y);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Color (" + x + ", " + y + "): " + touchColor);
        if (touchColor == Integer.MIN_VALUE) return null;
        return getAreaFromColor(touchColor);
      }

      public String getAreaFromColor(int color) {
        for (Integer colorKey : areasMap.keySet()) {
          if (matchColor(colorKey, color, DEFAULT_TOLERANCE)) {
            return areasMap.get(colorKey);
          }
        }
        return null;
      }

      private boolean matchColor(int color1, int color2, int tolerance) {
        if (Math.abs(Color.red(color1) - Color.red(color2)) > tolerance)
          return false;
        if (Math.abs(Color.green(color1) - Color.green(color2)) > tolerance)
          return false;
        if (Math.abs(Color.blue(color1) - Color.blue(color2)) > tolerance)
          return false;
        return true;
      }

      private int getTapColor(int x, int y) {
        try {
          // Convert coordinates for scaled bitmap
          float[] eventXY = new float[]{x, y};
          Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
          imageViewAreas.getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);
          invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
          x = (int) eventXY[0];
          y = (int) eventXY[1];

          // Get bitmap
          Drawable imgDrawable = imageViewAreas.getDrawable();
          Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

          // Get color
          return bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
      }
    }
```

You'll need the following dependence in order to get it working:

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.2'
```

To instantiate the previous class you can do it as follows:

```
imageView = new ZoneTapImageView(getActivity());
imageView.setImageResources(R.drawable.body_image, R.drawable.invisielb_areas_image);
imageView.setAreasMap(bodyParts);
imageView.setOnAreaObtainedListener(new OnAreaObtainedListener() {
  @Override
  public void OnArea(final String area) {
    Log.d("MapTouch", "Area:  " + area);
    // Area here is such "part_1" or "part_2"
    if (area != null) {
      // Handle your bodyPart click
    }
  }
});
```

And that's all. Hope I didn't miss any code and hope this helps you.

Comment: Great @SriramR , it would be fine to accept the answer in order to help other users with same problem

Comment: One suggestion, instead of using colors, you can use the android:tag property in each invisible view to assign a TAG. You can then get the TAG from the view clicked and then work accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to store the coordinates of the body points in the actual image. And then simply check if the click coordinates are within coordinates of the body points. You should also make sure to scale the points by using the imageview's matrix and it's coordinates on screen

For example if

```
        class BodyPoint{
              String name;
              int x;
              int y;
              public(String name,int x,int y){
                   this.name = name;
                   this.x = x;
                   this.y = y;}
             }
        BodyPoint headCoordinates = new BodyPoint ("head",50,20);
        BodyPoint neckCoordinates = new BodyPoint ("neck",50,50);
        BodyPoint leftHandCoordinates = new BodyPoint ("leftHand",10,50);
        BodyPoint rightHandCoordinates = new BodyPoint ("rightHand",80,50);

        BodyPoint[] bodyCoordinates = new BodyPoint[]{headCoordinates,neckCoordinates,
        leftHandCoordinates ,rightHandCoordinates };

    yourImgView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
                yourImgView.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);

    int touchX = (int) event.getX();
    int touchY = (int) event.getY();

    int imageX = touchX - viewCoords[0]; // viewCoords[0] is the X coordinate
    int imageY = touchY - viewCoords[1]; 
    Matrix mMatrix = getImageMatrix();
    float[] f = new float[9];
    mMatrix .getValues(f);

   float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
   float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

    processTouchedPoints(imageX/(int)scaleX , imageY/(int)scaleY );
            return true;

        }
    });

    ...
    int range = 50;
    void processTouchedPoints(int imageX,int imageY){
      foreach(BodyPoint mBodyPoint:bodyCoordinates ){
    int x = mBodyPoint.x;
    int y = mBodyPoint.y;
          if((imageX> (x-range) && imageX<(x+range))
           &&(imageY> (y-range) && imageY<(y+range))){
           doWhatever(mBodyPoint.name)
         }
      }
    }
```